# How can I add Components to a Jira project?

Tags: jira

In one of our Jira project "Components" field is set up, but in an other project I can not see it. Any idea how to get it to see? I made myself Administrator in this project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [add components to the project](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver/organizing-work-with-components-939938952.html) and make sure that the components field is in the creation screen of the issues.

Comment: The problem is components field is not in the creation screen.